# Mark repeated strings in a R object with their correspondent number

Tags: r, string, enumeration

I would like to enumerate the strings in a object in a way that strings that appears more than one time are tagged as "stringX1", "string2" and so on.

This would be an input example:

```
strings <- c("stringQ", "stringW", "stringE", "stringQ")
```

The expected output would be:

```
stringOut <- c("stringQ1", "stringW1", "stringE1", "stringQ2")
```

Note that the "stringQ" is there two times, that's why I expect "stringQ1" and "stringQ2".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `ave`

```
paste0(strings, ave(strings, strings, FUN = seq_along))
```

---

Or if we start the numbering from duplicate elements

```
make.unique(strings, sep="")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `dplyr` as follows:

```
require(dplyr)

strings <- data.frame(string = c("stringQ", "stringW", "stringE", "stringQ"))

strings %>% group_by(string) %>%
  mutate(stringnumber = paste0(string,row_number())) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(stringnumber)
```

results in :

```
# A tibble: 4 x 1
stringnumber
<chr>
1     stringQ1
2     stringW1
3     stringE1
4     stringQ2
```